# Customize googleVis Sankey diagrams in R to add customised tool tip

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, googlevis, sankey-diagram

I managed to plot a sankey diagram as following, col1 contains the ids

```
set.seed(1000)
df <- data.frame(col1= sample(c(1:15), 15, replace = F),
col2=sample(c("aa", "bb","cc"), 15, replace=TRUE),
col3=sample(c('a','b','c','d'), 15, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.20, 0.30)))

grp<-df %>%
group_by(col2, col3) %>%
summarise(n=n())
View(grp)
```

[image]

```
Sankeyy <- gvisSankey(grp, from="col2", to="col3", weight="n",
                  options=list(
                    sankey="{link: {color: { fill: '#d799ae' } },
                    node: { color: { fill: '#a61d4c' },
                    label: { color: '#871b47' } }}"))
plot(Sankeyy)
```

[image]

The following helps to keep track of ids belonging to each group

```
grp<-df %>%
group_by(col2, col3) %>%
summarise(n=n(), rows=paste(sort(col1), collapse = ", "))
View(grp)
```

[image]

```
Sankeyy <- gvisSankey(grp, from="col2", to="col3", weight="n",
                  options=list(
                    sankey="{link: {color: { fill: '#d799ae' } },
                    node: { color: { fill: '#a61d4c' },
                    label: { color: '#871b47' } }}"))
plot(Sankeyy)
```

But I get the following error.

[image]

Whats the proper way to include the ids belonging to each group in the sankey diagram tooltip?

Answer (score 1):

In order for a sankey chart tooltip to work, the column that you're using as a tooltip has to be named *something.tooltip*. The data must also be of type "character" (though you don't have a problem with this.)

If I change your column name to follow the *.tooltip* format, everything works fine.

```
grp<-df %>%
group_by(col2, col3) %>%
summarise(n=n(), rows.tooltip=paste(sort(col1), collapse = ", "))
```

[Sankey chart with custom tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNp4l.png)

Side note: it appears that for other gvis chart types, the name of your tooltip column has to include the name of the data column it is meant to serve as a tooltip for: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/Using_Roles_via_googleVis.html

I haven't played around with this, so I can't comment on the specifics. Nevertheless, for sankey charts the above is all you need.